# TV left on during Shabbat for serious reasons

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, performance-entertainment

The question of leaving a TV on for all of Shabbat was asked here before and was answered: No, it is against the spirit of Shabbat, plus other halachic reasons.

But what if you did it to stay abreast of fast-changing events in your community or the country, that may affect you or require some action on your part?  (Example: a fast-approaching hurricane.)

Comment: There's hurricane guidance from a Florida rabbi which said to leave a radio on for just this reason. Radio is preferable to TV, for lots of reasons. (Practically, it can be battery-powered...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OU's guidance on hurricane preparation](https://www.ou.org/news/ou-rca-shabbat-protocols-in-case-of-a-hurricane-or-other-disasters/), developed by Rabbi Kenneth Brander (when he was in Boca Raton).

```
Television or Radio

  TV or radio should be left on in a side room.

  A streaming radio app set up before Shabbat/Yom Tov can also 
  be used in a side room (this might not be such a good suggestion
  as a lost internet connection may affect the app).
  
  The TV or radio should only be used to listen to the news.

  Channel should not be changed.

  Volume on radio (if dials are not digital) may be adjusted 
  on Shabbat or Yom Tov. Better to keep it on low for it preserves 
  the battery and only raise volume if necessary.
```

---

For the spirit of shabbos, then, this should not be in the living room. Put it someplace that you'd need to go actively check.

As the article stated, an old-fashioned radio with a volume knob has advantages over anything with digital buttons.

And, just to stress once again -- this is for something pressing like hurricanes, floods, wildfires, or riots. Not the latest football score.