Feeling lonely on shabbat
Im single guy, in my 30s. Trying to be more observent on shabbat. I go to shul on shabbat. Its great. I don't really have any friends in my community. I go alot to friends for Shabbat who don't live near by. And sleeping by them is not an option. My biggest problem is being alone on shabbat. Coming home after davening on Friday night. Is what gets to me the most. I would do kiddush and have my meal infront of the tv. And that keeps me sane. My plan for know is to leave the tv turned on for Friday night and have it turned off via timer Friday night. My question is would that still be considered shomer shabbat on some level ? Is this permissable?. Shabbat day is easier for me because its short and i can just rest in between going to shul. But Friday night is what is really difficult for me. In my shul their isn't too many guys my age where i can join for the meal and their not big on guest. No other shuls in my area that im comfortable with. My hope is one day i can afford to move to the neighborhood where i do have friends and can observe shabbat more properly & not be lonely. Thank you

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/136403/33217. And: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65691/33217

Thanks for joining and for your question Israel. This is probably a question that is best to be asked to your rabbi, as this concerns practical advice.

I forget which Jewish organization interviewed a bunch of singles a few years back and wrote up some anonymized stories they encountered. "Lonely and left the TV on" was one of those. You should talk to your rabbi about your particulars, and I'm not saying whether it's permitted or not ... but for what it's worth, you're not alone in your predicament.

Please do not interpret the fact that this question will likely be closed as a sign that we are lacking in care and sympathy for your predicament... I can guarantee most, if not all here feel for you and the situation you are in and certainly wish you the best in finding a wholesome, healthy and kosher way to navigate this. That said, this question does not fit the format of this site which is designed to avoid issuing personal advice and personalized rulings of law.
